# How can I add custom HTML codes in template editor of Blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger, addthis

I wanted to add this code in the head tag of my blog on blogger —
http://www.techinfoblog.org/

When I tried to apply and save theme, it disappears after revisiting.

```
<script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="bcf035e7a7beeef231642bf9724d339c4268b018f3208344e694f2054d454233" async="async"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="bcf035e7a7beeef231642bf9724d339c4268b018f3208344e694f2054d454233" async="async"></script>

Comment: How it disappear? Please show error message!

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Layout
Click on Add Gadget
Choose HTML/JavaScript click sign +

More help here https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?visit_id=1-636308283545217153-181022040&p=templates&hl=hr&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

Use blogger classic theme as it allows normal HTML code without any template and then you could insert any html you want